# Generate unique ID for Vue component via mixin

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a mixin that should create a `uuid` (unique ID) property. The issue I'm having is that it's creating a new ID for each **usage within the same component**, whereas I expect the ID to be created once and be the same for the `id` and `for` attributes below.

### Mixin

The mixin that should provide the `uuid` property:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Identifiable',

  data: () => ({
    uuid: nanoid(),
  }),
})
```

### Component

The component I'm trying this out for. The ID should be the same for the `input` element's `id` and the `label` element's `for` attributes:

```
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input :id="uuid" :value="value" v-bind="$attrs" />
    <label v-if="label" :for="uuid">{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import mixins from 'vue-typed-mixins'
import Identifiable from '~/mixins/identifiable'

export default mixins(Identifiable).extend({
  name: 'Input',

  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },

    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

### Example output

Note the differing values on `id` and `for`.

```
<div class="input" data-v-e40e9e12="" data-v-55ba593f="">
  <input id="vZ51vQSLIncASUYcjNK13" value="..." data-v-e40e9e12="">
  <label for="-6mS5boxv1PPq5nhFQ4sP" data-v-e40e9e12="">...</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved out the uuid declaration so it's sure it's never reevaluated.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

const uuid = nanoid()

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Identifiable',

  data: () => ({
    uuid
  }),
})
```

Comment: @Renaud: Please remember to provide explanation for your code, instead of just including a code block as an answer. Can I ask you to edit your answer to provide additional detail?

Comment: @Renaud In this case it means the end result is identical.

Comment: If you could set-up a minimal reproduction that would maybe help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)